# How can I remove master password from command line in Ansiblized Kerberos KDC setup?

Tags: ansible, kerberos

I'm trying to set up a Kerberos KDC using Ansible. The first command I'm using is:

`/usr/bin/kdb5_util -r MYREALM create -s -P master_password`

The problem is that I don't want to specify my master password on the command line. The man page for `kdb5_util` implies the password can be supplied by file rather than command line [1] but I can't figure it out - do I specify it as a stash file or what?

(I could do it by using a shell script, but I'd prefer not to do it that way if I can avoid it.)

[1] "-m
specifies that the master database password should be read from the keyboard *rather than fetched from a file on disk*." (Emphasis mine.) https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/admin/admin_commands/kdb5_util.html#command-line-options

Comment: Have you already tried `arguments: { stdin: "sekrit password" }`? It [appears](https://github.com/krb5/krb5/blob/krb5-1.19.1-final/src/kadmin/dbutil/kdb5_util.c#L439) that the password prompt only asks once

Comment: I have not tried that. I'll give it a go and see if it works.